# Can't get test code to find source code using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I'm using gradle. I only have one project, broken up into source files, then test files. My test code cannot see the source code. When the test code tries to compile, it just says that the source code packages are not present. What gives?

When running "gradle build", or "gradle test", I get the following:

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Sample compilation error (because there's hundreds of these)

```
/tst/ContactsTests.java:1: error: package HoaryGuts does not exist
import HoaryGuts.AlertsHandlers;
                ^
```

Gradle build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task getHomeDir << {
    println gradle.gradleHomeDir
}

sourceSets {
    source {
        java {
            srcDir "src"
        }
        resources {
            srcDir "resources"
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir "tst"
        }
        compileClasspath = compileClasspath + configurations.compileOnly
    }
}

test {
    println "In the test function"
    useTestNG()
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }

    afterTest { desc, result ->
        println "${desc.className} ${desc.name} ${result.resultType}"
    }

    outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.9.10'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like maven, gradle uses `main` for production sources. These are normally defined under `src/main/java` for Java and `test` includes them just like it includes `compile` dependencies alongside of `testCompile`.

There is a reason for having `src` followed by a named configuration, followed by language: in your setup you do not provide a location for test resources which are very common and you make it more cumbersome to include other JVM languages such as Kotlin or Scala into the project. Maybe you do not need those, but there are rarely no good reasons to strongly deviate from the industry standard.

In any case, you did not move your `main` to a different location, you introduced a new source set `source` in addition to `main` (actually preserving main where they originally were). If you just specified new `srcDir` for `main` instead of introducing `source` (as you did for test) you would not need to extend `compileClasspath` and your main sources would be found in test.

If you do really want to stick to `source` rather than using `main` at a new location, in `test` you should add `source` `compileClasspath` and `output` to the classpath for test:

```
compileClasspath += sourceSets.source.compileClasspath + source.output + [whatever else you want to add]
```

But well, it is a poor choice.